# Using Python 2.7 and RawInput how do I load code into a string variable then convert to all uppercase?

Tags: python

I need to convert a file into a string using raw input then convert the characters to uppercase?  How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

To convert a string `s` to uppercase: `s.upper()`.

You use raw input like this:

```
name = raw_input("What is your name? ")
print "Hello, %s." % name
```